# Parser lento em PHP

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um `parser` completo de um site, pra alterar todos os `hrefs`
 e `src`, faz parte de um sistema que estou a desenvolver, hoje fui na casa de um amigo que tem a internet de 1Mega apenas, aqui por onde moro a velocidade da internet é algo crítico, e o sistema vai rodar mais por aqui, então me preocupei porque lá demorou muito para abrir o site com o `parser`, usei muitos `str_replace`, tentei usar o `DOM` mas acho que não ficaria viável para um site inteiro.

O Servidor que o script está a correr é um dedicado simples, ele tem o ping meio alto por estar no exterior e uso https, teria o servidor algo a ver com o lenteza?
Alguém me aconselharia usar outro método para substitui os links do site?

Comment: A velocidade da internet não vai afetar nada o processamento. A única coisa que ela afetaria é se você estiver trafegando dados sem necessidade.

Comment: Mas aqui em casa minha conexão é de 3 megas, e o ping é menor, e abre quase 5 vezes mais rápido.

Comment: Creio que haja 2 possíveis causas: *1*) Muito conteúdo pesado para a internet de 1MB; *2*) Seus métodos estão causando lentidão no processo.

Comment: O Que mais usei foi `str_replace`, tentei o `DOM`, mas era muitos links diferentes e acabava ficando mais pesado com o `DOM`.

Comment: Fazer `parser` naturalmente é lento, mas você tem que identificar a causa primeiro! Não adianta achar que a culpa é do `str_replace` e carregar imagens de 10MB... Faça um debug, e veja no console do navegador o que está carregando.

Comment: Vou fazer isso @PapaCharlie

Comment: Então o problema é o volume de dados, se você está enviando dados desnecessário, pare de fazer isto. Isto nada tem a ver com o processamento. Se está enviando só o necessário, não tem nada que você possa fazer para resolver este problema. Se o problema for o parser a velocidade da  conexão não vai afetar nada. Torná-lo mais rápido só fara ele ficar esperando por mais tempo do que já está.

Comment: é complicado responder sem ver o que está fazendo.